# How to eliminate empty columns to be inserted to DB if CSV files contains empty columns?

Tags: java, csv

I have a table in database with 5 columns. In CSV file I have data like below.  How to process it into Oracle database by elimating empty columns (because CSV file contains 6 columns, it will mismatch in database columns having 5 columns).

```
    111, ,John,2000,   ,US 
    222, ,Alle,3000,   ,China
    333, ,Kite,4000,LCD,IND
    444, ,King,5000,LED,Aust

package com.java;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Vector;
public class Test3 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        try 
        {
            int commas = 0;
            List data = new Vector();
            List columnCount = new Vector();
            String[] cols = null;
            String[] strArray = null;
            String file = "D:/temp/CSV/data.csv";
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
            String line = br.readLine();
            do
            {       
                commas = 0;
                cols = line.split(",");
                strArray = new String[cols.length];
                int i=0;
                for (String element : cols) 
                {    
                    if (!isBlank(element))
                    {                   
                        strArray[i] = element;
                        i++;
                    }
                }
                int newFile = line.length();
                for(int k = 0; k < newFile; k ++ )
                {
                    char eachChar = line.charAt(k);         
                    if(eachChar == ',')
                    {
                        commas ++;
                    }
                }

                data.add(strArray); 
                line = br.readLine();           
            }
            while (line != null);       
            Vector columns = new Vector(commas + 1);
            for(int i = 0; i < commas +1 ; i ++ )
            {
                columns.add("" + i);               
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {

        }
    }
    public static boolean isBlank(String str) {
        int strLen;

        if (str == null || (strLen = str.length()) == 0) 
        {

            return true;
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < strLen; i++) 
        {
            if ((Character.isWhitespace(str.charAt(i)) == false)) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;

    }

}
```

Comment: what have you done so far?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a util method to check if it is empty string or not.

```
public static boolean isBlank(String str) {
        int strLen;
        if (str == null || (strLen = str.length()) == 0) {
            return true;
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < strLen; i++) {
            if ((Character.isWhitespace(str.charAt(i)) == false)) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
```

and use it in your reader like below

```
Scanner s = null;
        try {
            s = new Scanner(new File("D:/sri/Test.txt"));
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        while (s.hasNextLine()) {
            String[] line = s.nextLine().split(",");
            for (String element : line) {
                if (!isBlank(element))
                    System.out.println(element);
            }

        }
```

Comment: but,here i am reading each line as a String[] and storing it in datavector (Vector type) and by taking comma count iam preparing one more vector to assume number of columns and storing in DB,by passing both datavector and columncount vector.With your suggestions how can i get this...

Comment: For your use case use isBlank(str) to find the null value if value is null just put default value like for int data type 0.

Comment: Could you please explain clearly ,as iam not getting your point

Comment: Sorry for delay edited my question I want data(Vector) only for non empty columns